# Extremely Rare Events/Model Predicts No Occurrences

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics

I'm trying to put together a model to predict rare claims, about 0.3% chance of occurrence.  My file has 70,000 work orders (opportunities for a claim) and about 200 claims.

I've manually created a model that identifies a subset of work orders that have about a 1% chance of a claim, just with excel, manual classification, and pivot tables.  I'm trying to improve on that, and some data scientists have pointed me in a couple directions.

I've used KNIME, both a random forest and logistic predictor.  Both models simply predict that no work orders have a damage, which technically is 99.7% accurate but not very helpful.

If I could predict a claim with a 5-10% accuracy that would be very valuable.

Outcome is binary (claim/no claim).  Three inputs, all categorical.  Each input has 4-10 different categories.

Comment: Much has been said about this on this site. As a quick fix, use another metric other than accuracy.

Comment: What I care about most is True Positives/Positives, but there are no positives...

Comment: Your Positives will depend on your classifiers threshold. As @user2974951 said, use a threshold-independent metric to evaluate your model and then choose an adequate threshold subsequently.

Comment: I understand now.  I just need to figure out how to do it in that software